# In Rails, how do I output my date as a time in milliseconds in my CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, date, ruby-on-rails-5, milliseconds

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.  I use the following code to output my table data to CSV form ...

```
  def self.to_csv(from_date, to_date)
    attributes = %w{index_date value} #customize columns here
    values = CryptoIndexValue.where('index_date >= ? and index_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)
                                     .order(index_date: :desc)

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      values.each do |value|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| value.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is, when my date (a PostGres 9.5 timestamp column) is output, it is output as

```
2017-08-01 20:00:09 UTC
```

I would like it to get output as the time in milliseconds.  How can I adjust the above to output my time as a time in milliseconds rather than the default date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call `.to_i` on a DateTime object:

```
timestamp = DateTime.now.to_i
# => 1501617998
DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s, '%s')
# => Tue, 01 Aug 2017 20:07:10 +0000
```

The timestamp is the seconds since Epoch. Multiply it by a thousand and you get milliseconds.

In your case, you must make a hook for this case:

```
attr_values = attributes.map do |attr| 
  attr_value = value.send(attr)
  attr_value = attr_value.to_i * 1000 if attr_value.is_a?(DateTime)
  attr_value
end
csv << attr_values
```

This means everytime an attribute returns a DateTime object, it will be converted to a timestamp * 1000. If you want to filter only few attrs to convert DateTime -> Timestamp, test the `attr` with a whitelist instead of testing `attr_value`'s class.

Comment: I'm unclear where I would put that in the code I have provided.  I'm outputting lines to a csv using the line "csv << attributes.map{ |attr| value.send(attr) }"

Comment: You'll have to make a hook for certain values before outputting them in the CSV. I will update my code in a sec

Comment: In my case the class was a "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone".  Substituting that made everything work.